# jQuery Dialog box Drop Up

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog({ width: 'auto', zIndex: 9999, height: 370, resizable: false, draggable: false,
    open :function(event, ui) {
        jQuery('body').addClass('black-overlay');
    },
    show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up", mode: 'slow'},
    close:function(event, ui) {
        jQuery('body').removeClass('black-overlay');
    } 
});
```

I want Dialog Window Should be Drop From Starting of Browser window and No border to that dialog box

and also drop from top Should be slow

Currently dialog box is Drop up very fastly and not from Starting of Browser window

Can any one help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reduce the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect

```
    $.fx.speeds._default = 3000;
```

Put this code just before:

```
 jQuery( "#dialog" ).dialog({...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add duration:1000 to the show properties

`show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up", mode: 'slow' ,duration:1000}`